# Magento 2: How to change sku dynamically in configurable product view page?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, product-view

The configurable product based on variation product images are changing, but not SKU, is there any way to change SKU also?

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `function getAllSizeImages()` from `Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data.php` file.

```
 protected function getAllSizeImages(Product $product, $imageFile)
    {
        return [
            'large' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')
                ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
                ->setImageFile($imageFile)
                ->getUrl(),
            'medium' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')
                ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
                ->setImageFile($imageFile)
                ->getUrl(),
            'small' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                ->setImageFile($imageFile)
                ->getUrl(),
            'sku' => $product->getSku()
        ];
    }
```

After change variant of product you have got response with sku of variant and you can change sku based on response using js.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, the *images* and the *price* will change. **But not SKU.**

More information about which elements on the page change when options are selected can be found here: `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()`.

In order to display the SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing `SKU` for each simple product.

Switching `SKU` when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.